# R statistical Programing

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am trying to write R codes for the histogram plot and save each histogram separate file using the following command. 
I have a data set "Dummy" and i want to plot each histogram by a column name and there will be 100 histogram plots in total...
I have the following R codes that draws the each Histogram...

```
library(ggplot2)
i<-1
for(i in 1:100)
{
  jpeg(file="d:/R Data/hist.jpeg", sep=",")
  hist(Dummy$colnames<-1, ylab= "Score",ylim=c(0,3),col=c("blue"));
  dev.off()
  i++
    if(i>100)
      break()
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've come from another programming language, so you've got a few things here you don't need, and some things missing you do need. Particularly, how will each plot differ? It looks like you're calling the same data every time?

Comment: `Dummy$colnames<-1` doesn't make sense in your loop. Are you trying to assign a new object?

Answer (score 2):

As a start, let's get your for loop into R a little better by taking out the lines trying to change `i`, your `for` loop will do that for you.

We'll also include a `file=` value that changes with each loop run.

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
  jpeg(file = paste0("d:/R Data/hist", i, ".jpeg"))
  hist(Dummy[[i]], ylab = "Score", ylim = c(0, 3), col = "blue")
  dev.off()
}
```

Now we just need to decide what you want to plot. Will each plot be different? How will each plot extract the data it needs?

EDIT: I've taken a stab at what you're trying to do. Are you trying to take each of 100 columns from the `Dummy` dataset? If so, `Dummy[[i]]` should achieve that (or `Dummy[,i]` if Dummy is a matrix).

Comment: if you want to change the column selected for the plot, shouldn't it be `Dummy[ , i]`?

Comment: @loki, since data.frames are secretly lists, list indexing will select certain columns.

Comment: No `ggplot2` needed, by the way.

Comment: Right you are, sorry. My syntax there works for a data.table, but not for a matrix or data.frame. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @rosscova, `Dummy[[i]]` _does_ work for data.frames. E.g. `mtcars[[1]]`. It fails on matrices though (it selects a single value, columnwise).

Comment: @Axeman, interesting. I'm going with what I think are the more commonly used tabular format then (dataframe), and including the matrix version for completeness.

Comment: @Axeman you got me thinking on this, and I've posed [a separate question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263734/column-referencing-i-vs-i-for-matrix-dataframe-and-data-table)