# Column referencing: [[i]] vs [,i] for matrix, dataframe, and data.table

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data.table

Could someone please explain to me the difference in column referencing between `matrix`, `data.frame`, and `data.table`? I'm getting my head around which syntax to use for each class, but I don't understand how/why they're different.

Take a 10x10 matrix

```
foo <- matrix( nrow = 10, ncol = 10 )
```

I'll just fill the 2nd column to demonstrate:

```
foo[,2] <- rnorm(10)
head( foo, 3 )

        [,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]   NA -0.4688874   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [2,]   NA -1.0273370   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [3,]   NA -0.3981627   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Now I can reference the 2nd column with `foo[,2]`, but `foo[[2]]` returns only 1 cell, which in this case is NA:

```
foo[,2]
 [1]  0.18340527  0.46511236 -2.43277107  0.13260218  0.20227436 -0.57518392 -0.62211864  2.00239088  -0.09561907  0.67536428

foo[[2]]
  [1] NA
```

If I change the matrix to a dataframe, both referencing methods work:

```
foo <- data.frame( foo )
foo[,2]
  [1] -0.4688874 -1.0273370 -0.3981627 -0.2207062  0.5711004  1.1085851 -1.3343338  0.2337622  -1.0632469 -0.9783714


foo[[2]]
  [1] -0.4688874 -1.0273370 -0.3981627 -0.2207062  0.5711004  1.1085851 -1.3343338  0.2337622  -1.0632469 -0.9783714
```

Now if I convert to a `data.table` only the second method works, and the first method returns the value 2 (which isn't in the table at all):

```
foo[,2]
  [1] 2
foo[[2]]
  [1] -0.4688874 -1.0273370 -0.3981627 -0.2207062  0.5711004  1.1085851 -1.3343338  0.2337622  -1.0632469 -0.9783714
```

So my question is, why the different syntax for different classes? And is there a particular syntax that would work for all 3 classes, or do we need to know/check the tabular class before knowing how to call a reference?

EDIT: also interesting here is that row referencing is more consistent across classes.

For matrix, dataframe, and data.table respectively:

```
foo[2,]
 [1]        NA 0.4651124        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA

foo <- data.frame( foo )
foo[2,]
  X1        X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
2 NA 0.4651124 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA

setDT( foo )
foo[2,]
  X1        X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1: NA 0.4651124 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: You have a good point, and as much as I enjoy using R, this lack of consistency in cell referencing between matrix, data.frame, and data.table types is frustrating, especially for new useRs.  And you haven't even gotten to lists yet.... Or have you? ;)

Comment: @N8TRO not in this context, no. But yes, maybe they should get a mention too!

Comment: There's substantial information in `?"[["` and `?"["` and `?"[.data.frame"`. Did you take a look?  As for `data.table` syntax, as far as I know it was purely a design decision by its main author. Also note that a matrix is just a vector with dimension attributes whereas a data.frame is fundamentally a `list`

Comment: When it comes to referencing in different data types, I found the book "[Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)" by Hadley Wickham really good explained. However, it does not address `data.tables`.

Comment: Every function used among "class"es has, also, respective methods. The fact that the `print` method for some classes coincides (i.e. a "matrix", "data.frame", "data.table" _look_ alike) does not mean that they, also, will/should/are-built-to behave similarly. You could, yourself, make a "matrix"-like class and define/document the essential `[` and `[<-` method that will behave appropriately to your class.

Comment: @docendodiscimus no, I haven't. In fact, I've never thought to search help for symbols, I've only ever used it for functions themselves. I will definitely have a close look, thank you.

Comment: @rosscova all of those are in fact functions themselves.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I've learned since posting this question here (with a lot of help from the commenters!), which have helped me to understand the differences I mentioned. If anyone could please clarify anything I'm getting wrong here, I'd appreciate it:

- Objects of class `matrix`, `data.frame`, and `data.table` are all `list` objects under the hood, but they differ in an important way.
- Each column of a `data.frame` or `data.table` object is an element of the list "under its hood", meaning that a column can be extracted in the same way as a list element would be, hence `foo[[2]]` works great for calling the second column in both of those classes.
- A `matrix` differs in that every *cell* is an element of the list, meaning that `foo[[2]]` will only retrieve one cell, rather than a column (which brings us to...).
- Those list items making up the `matrix` are "filled" column-wise (top-to-bottom, left-to-right), so the call `foo[[2]]` is retrieving the second item, which here resides in row 2 of column 1.
- Since the `matrix` does also have dimensions, `foo[,2]` is accepted as referring to the second column, as it does for a `data.frame` object.
- A `data.table` object (up until recently, see next point) didn't have a particularly logical response to the call `foo[,2]`, and returned the value `2` regardless of the data to which it was referring, for no good reason I can find.
- As of very recent updates to the `data.table` package (as of 1.9.8 I think? Thank you maintainers!) the syntax `foo[,2]` is now logically accepted as per a `data.frame`, so some of the confusion which lead to my question has been superseded!

So in conclusion:

1. All of the objects I mentioned in my question are actually lists (which means I now get @N8TRO's joke in the comments, to which I was naively oblivious before), with both `data.table` and `data.frame` containing a list element for each column, and a `matrix` containing a list element for each cell (this makes the `[[` call make sense to me now).
2. All of the objects mentioned have dimensions, which means (as of recent `data.table` package updates) the `foo[,2]` syntax works the same for all 3 classes. YAY!

Thank you so much to the commenters for pointing me in the right direction (and making jokes that I now get). I hope this might help someone in the future who comes across the same confusion I did.